# Does Windows 8 have to be installed on NTFS?

Tags: windows, windows-8, filesystems, ntfs, fat32

Does Windows 8 need to be installed on an NTFS partition or does it just like to be on one?

If I installed it on NTFS and then copied all its files on to a FAT32 partition would it work or would it throw a tantrum and refuse to work?

Comment: Why do you want to install on a FAT32 partition? A filesystem that hasn't seen any real updates in almost 20 years?

Comment: @MichaelThorpe I have a 64GB flash-drive and it needs to be fat32 because it has other bootable tools that work with Linux and Linux doesn't support write to NTFS natively.

Comment: You can have multiple partitions on your flash drive.

Comment: I happily read and write files in NTFS partitions from Ubuntu (12.10). I have both compressed and uncompressed files, and neither causes problems. But if you're bothered create a FAT32 transfer partition.

Comment: Another solution if you can't get NTFS writing to work with your Linux system (I have some systems based on older Debian versions that can't write to NTFS, so I understand that it can be an issue if you're stuck with out-of-date tools) would be to create a file on the drive that is mounted as a loopback device, and use one of the filesystem merging systems as your root.  Look at how live CDs with persistent storage features work, e.g. the Ubuntu install CD.

Comment: Not sure enough to make this an answer, but I think you can also install Windows 7 and 8 on [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), although exFAT is primary meant for flash drives.

Comment: You want to install multiple OSs on a 64GB drive? You call it a "Flash Drive", is it an external flash-drive or an SSD? Because I don't believe that Windows 8 can be installed on a typical external drive.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Windows NT 6.x cannot be installed to a FAT or FAT32 partition, because they make extensive use of advanced features of the NTFS filesystem, like [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) and [junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

Besides, allowing users to install to FAT/FAT32 in previous versions provided a false sense of security, since these filesystems do not support [access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). Remember that one of the much-touted features of Vista was increased security.

Comment: How about an ext4 partition?

Comment: @shortstheory Not without access to the Windows source — you would need to add support to the bootloader.

Answer (score 14):

Windows Vista and higher won't install to FAT32, and can only be installed to an NTFS partition. This is probably due to the use of symlinks, which is not supported in FAT32.

As for copying files, thats a no. Windows needs to be installed in order for the installer to configure your boot order properly. Just copying files won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install windows on a FAT partition. You shouldn't use a FAT partition for your Windows install. You can use a program like AOMEI partition manager to create a new partition, but you can't delete your existing partition.

Comment: You should specify the Windows version you're talking about in the answer. Many versions of Windows (basically everything through XP) could/can be installed to a FAT partition.

Comment: @AndrewMedico while it of course doesn't hurt to be specific, it's pretty clear from the context of the question - which is asking about Windows 8, that is what is meant.

Comment: Windows 9x have no idea of NTFS, not even install on it. Windows XP can be installed on both FAT32 and NTFS but not FAT16 or FAT12